# SQL Pivot table for Blank data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

following is my Query to generate the Pivoted result:

```
SELECT '# of Corrective Actions open and overdue' as [Corrective Actions breakdown], 
[405],
[2865],
[3142],
[405]+[2865]+[3142] as [Total]
FROM
(Select il.Locationid , ca.CorrectiveActionsid, il.locOrder, ca.isDeleted caDeleted, i.isDeleted iDeleted, i.CompanyId companyid,ca.CADateBy, ca.Status  from IncidentLocation il inner join incident i on il.IncidentId = i.IncidentId 
inner join CorrectiveActions ca on i.IncidentId = ca.IncidentId  
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
COUNT(CorrectiveActionsid)
FOR LocationId IN ([405],[2865],[3142])
) PivotTable 

where locOrder = 0 and caDeleted =0 and iDeleted = 0 and companyId = 210
and CADateBy <= '2013-01-01'  and [Status] = 'Open'
```

I was thinking for blank data the count should return o. But I am getting no result at all. Please guide me what wrong I am doing and what should I do to get zero instead of blank for all the counted values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your query doesn't return any row, you can fix it like this (I've not fixed other parts of query, just want to show you a workaround):

```
select
    A.[Corrective Actions breakdown],
    coalesce([405], 0) as [405],
    coalesce([2865], 0) as [2865],
    coalesce([3142], 0) as [3142],
    coalesce([405], 0) + coalesce([2865], 0) + coalesce([3142], 0) as [Total]
from (select '# of Corrective Actions open and overdue' as [Corrective Actions breakdown]) as A
    outer apply (
   SELECT
        [405],
        [2865],
        [3142]
   FROM
        (Select il.Locationid , ISNULL(ca.CorrectiveActionsid, 0) AS CorrectiveActionsid, il.locOrder, ca.isDeleted caDeleted, i.isDeleted iDeleted, i.CompanyId companyid,ca.CADateBy, ca.Status  from IncidentLocation il inner join incident i on il.IncidentId = i.IncidentId 
        inner join CorrectiveActions ca on i.IncidentId = ca.IncidentId  
        ) AS SourceTable
   PIVOT
        (
        COUNT(CorrectiveActionsid)
        FOR LocationId IN ([405],[2865],[3142])
        ) PivotTable 
        where locOrder = 0 and caDeleted =0 and iDeleted = 0 and companyId = 210
    and CADateBy <= '2013-01-01'  and [Status] = 'Open'
    ) as p
```

Comment: Can you please give me a little brief what you are actually trying to accomplish ? "I am getting  Incorrect syntax near )" error. Yes certainly it is returning no rows but what I am trying to get is counted value to be zero event if there is no data in the SourceTable.

Comment: the idea is to get simple select one row with name, join your data to it and use coalesce if some of the counts is null

Comment: Nope. Still returning 0 rows.

Comment: ok, change this to outer apply (see updated) or left outer join ... on 1 = 1

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the `count()` to return 0.  If it doesn't, you can try using `coalesce()`:

```
coalesce([405], 0) as [405]
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server COUNT will ignore NULL values.  That being said, use an ISNULL function on the column you are going to aggregate.

```
   SELECT '# of Corrective Actions open and overdue' as [Corrective Actions breakdown], 
        [405],
        [2865],
        [3142],
        [405]+[2865]+[3142] as [Total]
   FROM
        (Select il.Locationid , ISNULL(ca.CorrectiveActionsid, 0) AS CorrectiveActionsid, il.locOrder, ca.isDeleted caDeleted, i.isDeleted iDeleted, i.CompanyId companyid,ca.CADateBy, ca.Status  from IncidentLocation il inner join incident i on il.IncidentId = i.IncidentId 
        inner join CorrectiveActions ca on i.IncidentId = ca.IncidentId  
        ) AS SourceTable
   PIVOT
        (
        COUNT(CorrectiveActionsid)
        FOR LocationId IN ([405],[2865],[3142])
        ) PivotTable 

   where locOrder = 0 and caDeleted =0 and iDeleted = 0 and companyId = 210
        and CADateBy <= '2013-01-01'  and [Status] = 'Open'
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax  near CorrectiveActionsid. Expecting '(',or SELECT.

Comment: I just edited my answer.  I moved the ISNULL to the SELECT in the SourceTable subquery.  Give that a try.

Comment: I basically just copied your query and added the ISNULL.  Do you get errors if you copy the query in your question into SSMS and run?

Comment: Nope, I don get any error for the query with isnull moved to SourceTable query. Just producing the same blank result.

Comment: What do you mean by blank result?  No result? NULL? Empty String?

Comment: I mean nothing. Query executed successfully with 0 rows returned.